# Evaluating $\frac1{3^k}+\frac1{6^k}+\frac1{10^k}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

The series $\frac1{3^k}+\frac1{6^k}+\frac1{10^k}+\cdots$ for integers $k>1$ at the triangular numbers can be written as $$\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac1{\left(\frac{i(i+1)}2\right)^k}=2^k\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac1{(i(i+1))^k}$$ At first glance, the zeta function may be of use. Partial fractions can be used to evaluate the sum, but only for small values of $k$ since the general formula is $$\frac1{i^k(i+1)^k}=\frac{a_1}i+\frac{a_2}{i^2}+\cdots+\frac{a_k}{i^k}+\frac{b_1}{i+1}+\frac{b_2}{(i+1)^2}+\cdots+\frac{b_k}{(i+1)^k}.$$ Of course, once the expression in the sum is presented as such, $\zeta(\cdot)$ can replace each individual term. However, apart from this tedious method, I do not see a way to get rid of the summation.

Is there another way?

Comment: Why start at i=2 and not at 1?

Comment: It might help if you solve first for specific k, like k=1 and k=2.

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ $k=1$ is trivial. For $k=2,3,4$, the sums are $-\frac{13}4+2\zeta(2)$, $-\frac{79}8-6\zeta(2)$ and $-\frac{561}{16}+20\zeta(2)+2\zeta(4)$ respectively. Looks like a negative coefficient, then terms of $\zeta(2s)$ for $s\ge 1$.

Comment: From the first values for $k$ which you gave, it appears that the result will be a weighted sum of  $\zeta(2 n) $ with $n = 0,1,\cdots,\lfloor k/2 \rfloor $, where the weights are integer fractions. Further, it is known that $\zeta(2 n) = \frac{p}{q} \pi^{2n}$ where $p,q $ are integers. [continued below]

Comment: [continued from above] So, if the trend for the result holds,  the general result  will be of the form $\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \frac{p_i}{q_i} \pi^{2i} $ where $p_i,q_i $ are integers. Since $\pi$ is irrational, this could only be simplified if it happens to be a perfect power in $\pi^2$, i.e. $a (\pi^2 + b)^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}$,  or at least partially so, with some lower power. It seems that this is not  the case, which would result in the fact that indeed you need some fractions expansion with at least $\lfloor k/2 \rfloor$ many terms.

Answer (score 2):

*Just a few values.*
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & -13+\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3} \\
 3 & 79-8 \pi ^2 \\
 4 & -561+\frac{160 \pi ^2}{3}+\frac{16 \pi ^4}{45} \\
 5 & 4031-\frac{1120 \pi ^2}{3}-\frac{32 \pi ^4}{9} \\
 6 & -29569+2688 \pi ^2+\frac{448 \pi ^4}{15}+\frac{128 \pi ^6}{945} \\
 7 & 219647-19712 \pi ^2-\frac{3584 \pi ^4}{15}-\frac{256 \pi ^6}{135} \\
 8 & -1647361+146432 \pi ^2+\frac{5632 \pi ^4}{3}+\frac{2048 \pi ^6}{105}+\frac{256
   \pi ^8}{4725} \\
 9 & 12446719-1098240 \pi ^2-\frac{73216 \pi ^4}{5}-\frac{11264 \pi
   ^6}{63}-\frac{512 \pi ^8}{525} \\
 10 & -94595073+\frac{24893440 \pi ^2}{3}+\frac{1025024 \pi ^4}{9}+\frac{292864 \pi
   ^6}{189}+\frac{11264 \pi ^8}{945}+\frac{2048 \pi ^{10}}{93555}
\end{array}
\right)$$